# KCFinder, Internal Server Error, The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Tags: server, hosting, kcfinder

[image: error code from KCfinder]

The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.

Please contact the server administrator at
webmaster@ddddd.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.

Comment: Internal server error means something failed on it; check your logs/enable error reporting. Btw, you left us no code here, as you tagged with "php" and "html".

Comment: thank you so much, This Kcfinder,, is created based on php and HTML that is why I tagged them. sorry about that, if i disturbed you.

Comment: Welcome. Oh, you didn't "disturb" me, it's just that when tags are used as you did, they tend to make the question unclear and misleading, where we expect to see (related) code for it. So, have you checked your logs to see if they contain anything in regards to error messages? If you don't have access to those and it is PHP related, you could enable PHP's error reporting to catch and display.

Comment: the best solution is to use error log or enables error